# Hadoop mapreducer value including string

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a dataset including

```
A B C
1 2 43
2 3 12
```

then I want to reduce it to print out as

```
1 2,43
2 3,12
```

My question is how could I include a string in value of  pairs?

Comment: The reducer can output any format. Can you share the code you currently have?

Comment: Hi Cricket, I figured out this part already and got another issue (with my code), can you take a look? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496984/variable-can-not-be-passed-into-for-loop