# Variable can not be passed into for loop

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, max, min

I have a data frame including sender (id, int), receiver(id, int), communication times (int).

```
A B C
1 5 10
1 6 20
1 7 20
1 8 11
```

my goal is to find the max communication times and return as 1 6,20 (format as A B,C) 
Since A1, B6 and A1, B7 both have max communication times 20, I just need to keep the smallest B id number.

In map step, I already separated A as key, (B,C) as value.

So far I can return the output with A and max C, but I have trouble to return the B value. My code below cannot change the min_Receiver, how can I fix this issue?

```
public static class IntSumReducer
extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
    //private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int max_val = 0;
    int val_str = 0;
    int val_str_1 = 0;
    int min_Receiver = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int tempReceiver = 0;
        for (Text val : values) {
    String[] compositeString = val.toString().split(",");
    val_str = Integer.parseInt(compositeString[1]);
    //tempReceiver = Integer.parseInt(compositeString[0]);
            if( val_str>max_val) {
                max_val = val_str;

    }


    }

   for (Text val_1 : values){
    String[] compositeString = val_1.toString().split(",");
    tempReceiver = Integer.parseInt(compositeString[0]);        
    val_str_1 = Integer.parseInt(compositeString[1]);

    if (val_str_1 == max_val && tempReceiver < min_Receiver)
        {
           min_Receiver =tempReceiver;
        }

    }

        //result.set(max_val);
        context.write(key, new Text(min_Receiver + "," + max_val));}}
```

Expect output would be

```
1 6,20
```

the actual output is

```
1 2147483647,20
```

In the map, I already separated A as key, and B,C as value. So the compositeString includes two variables. The format in value is B,C.

Comment: Shouldn't the first loop be looking at `compositeString[2]` ? Using a debugger or even printing some of the values will help you see what is going on.

Comment: No, values here just include B and C. A is key.

Comment: What is `Reducer`? Is this a Hadoop question? If so, tag it `hadoop`.

Comment: Yes, just added. Thank for this reminder.

Comment: Your data is space-separated values, so how did you expect `split(",")` to work?

Comment: Just keep a hashmap or list (whatever best works for you) to keep track of value 'B' against value 'C' e.g: new Hashmap<'c', 'b'> and compare it too to update. And at the end of your iteration, read from the hashmap. If your dataset is huge, you may prefer concurrent hash map as well along with parallel streams.

Comment: So as I added at the end, I already separated A as key, and B, C as value. So the value has , .

Comment: Since your data is not space-separated, then please edit question to clarify the data format, i.e. that the format of an element in `values` is. Seems that the key and `A` are entirely immaterial to the question and is just confusing the issue. Remove it so the question has a [**Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I already revised my question several times, hope this can meet the requirement...

Comment: to D V, I will try hashmap later, but now I want to know why my second loop does not work.

Comment: hello? look at ans pls

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your delimeter is

use a line like this to get the `Text` with the max time

```
Optional<Text> answer = StreamSupport.stream(values.spliterator(),false)  //all this does is get you a stream of Text
.max(Comparator.comparingInt(s->getComTime(s))); // return the object that evaluates to the max value if one exists
```

along with creating a method that gets the Communication time from a string/Text like this:

```
private static int getComTime(Text line){
    String[] vals = line.toString().split(",");
    return  Integer.parseInt(vals[2]);
}
```

the boolean option for the .stream() is if you want sequential=`false` or parallel =`true` .... if your delimiter is different or the object is a little different you may need to adjust `getComTime` but this should be pretty close to right.

get an Optional if you want to handle it that way.

then you can do

```
if(answer.isPresent()){/* got an answer do something with it */}
```

***Sry i did most of this with Strings instead of Text but this is updated let me know if there are any issues.